# WinRT information: DTD is prohibited

Tags: xml, windows-8, rss, windows-runtime

I am trying to retrieve an RSS feed using the following code:

```
feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedUri);
```

However, it is producing the above exception.  I've looked around and, despite the fact that one of the MS sample projects seemed to have the same bug, it seems relatively undocumented. Can somebody point in the the right direction, or explain what this error means?

Comment: XML with DTD is a security risk, it permits denial-of-service attacks.  The XML parser used to parse the feed has the ProhibitDtd property turned on by default.  You can't get to the underlying parser to turn it off.  If the site owner doesn't fix it then he ought to see the number of visits to the site steadily declining.  So feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, check the response from the source.** If it is Tumblr, for example, you might actually get a HTML consent page rather than RSS data.

I had to get the user to fill that form out first, then sign on, and then attempt RSS retrieval... that fixed it for me.